# Not able to access tomcat from unix

Tags: java, apache, unix, tomcat, web-applications

I have a war file which I had deployed in tomcat server - window and able to access it. Now in unix I installed tomcat and deployed the same war. Configured server.xml file providing ip on these places where localhost were present.

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="aaa.bb.cc.dd">
<Host name="aaa.bb.cc.dd"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

I tried http://aaa.bb.cc.dd:8080/MY_APP and my browser says could not connect to the latter.
What did I do wrong in this? Anything I missed out?

Thanks.

Comment: `8080` is a popular port. Check if tomcat is really listen on 8080.

Comment: Thanks. Am new to unix. How to check if tomcat listens to 8080?

Comment: At command prompt `netstat -np`.

Comment: Tried netstat -ln -np and got the result 
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      18252/java

Comment: In your URL, do you mean `aaa.bb.cc.dd` something like `192.168.1.1` ?

Comment: No.. Its simply :::8080. It doesnt contain any ip addr. :(

Comment: What gives browser for `http://aaa.bb.cc.dd:8080` ?

Comment: It is saying like "could not connect to http://192.0.0.1:8080

Comment: And `ifconfig` lists 192.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes thats right.. Its showing the same..

Comment: My UNIX instance doesn't contain http and httpd service under /bin. Not sure the problem is because of the latter. Kindly guide me. @PeterMmmm